# Combine without Aggregate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Long story short I'm reasonably new to T-SQL, and I'm working on querying some info out of JD Edwards for our scheduling department. We're a manufacturing plant, and the table that contains our Part info and the components that go into making each part uses a single column for all components with multiple rows for each so we can have a single part with twenty rows, I have two problems with this query that have me a little stumped, the first is that I'd like to see one row per work order, that contains all of the part info, from the WO table I use our Finished part number in the following query:

Raw data from necessary columns for this WO & Finished Product:

```
WALITM                      IXLITM                      WADOCO
TF2-10426IA                 CF-S1094P-UL                800059
TF2-10426IA                 CF-S1094P-UL                800059
TF2-10426IA                 CF-S1094P-UL                800059
TF2-10426IA                 CF-S1094P-UL                800059
TF2-10426IA                 TE2-06718                   800059
TF2-10426IA                 TE2-06718                   800059
TF2-10426IA                 TE2-06718                   800059
TF2-10426IA                 TE2-06718                   800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-TR23                     800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-TR23                     800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-TR23                     800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-TR23                     800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-BX35                     800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-BX35                     800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-BX35                     800059
TF2-10426IA                 RP-BX35                     800059
```

(Sorry apparently a complete n00b today, aside from creating an HTML table, couldn't figure out how to get this to format into a table)

```
    SELECT WO, TF, TE, CAP, LABEL
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Sched.dbo.TBS.WADOCO AS WO,
    Sched.dbo.TBS.WALITM AS TF,
    CASE WHEN Part.IXLITM LIKE 'TE%' THEN Part.IXLITM END AS TE,
    CASE WHEN Part.IXLITM LIKE 'CF%' THEN Part.IXLITM END AS CAP,
    CASE WHEN Part.IXLITM LIKE 'LBL%' THEN Part.IXLITM END AS LABEL
    FROM WB.dbo.Part
    INNER JOIN Sched.dbo.TBS ON TBS.WAAITM=Part.IXKITA) AS T2
    WHERE WO=800059
```

Which Yields:

```
WO          TF            TE          CAP            LABEL
800059      TF2-10426IA   NULL        NULL           NULL
800059      TF2-10426IA   NULL        CF-S1094P-UL   NULL
800059      TF2-10426IA   TE2-06718   NULL           NULL
```

I've made a couple of other attempts at getting everything combined in one line but haven't had any luck yet I think something similar to 'Group By' would be ideal...

The second part of this query that also has me a little stumped, although admittedly I've worked on the above more, is that I need to pull even more data out of the IXLITM column `Where IXKITA=[The TE2***] for the TF2*** Number`.

I think between the two issues I may look for a solution outside of T-SQL, but figured I'd ask for some insight from all you experts first.

Thanks in advance and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your desired output? Please provide a sample. And you have provided no data re table `TBS`.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly the second part? What extra data do you need to pull out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT WO, 
       TF, 
       TE, 
       CAP, 
       LABEL 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT WADOCO   AS WO, 
                        WALITM   AS TF, 
                        Max(CASE 
                              WHEN IXLITM LIKE 'TE%' THEN PART.IXLITM 
                              ELSE '' 
                            END) AS TE, 
                        Max(CASE 
                              WHEN IXLITM LIKE 'CF%' THEN PART.IXLITM 
                              ELSE '' 
                            END) AS CAP, 
                        Max(CASE 
                              WHEN IXLITM LIKE 'LBL%' THEN PART.IXLITM 
                              ELSE '' 
                            END) AS LABEL 
        FROM   PART 
        GROUP  BY WALITM, 
                  WADOCO)T2 
WHERE  WO = 800059
```

There's a working solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c204b/5).

Comment: Thanks Gidil, This did it for the first part once I added the Inner Join to get the WO data, and prefix the When IXLITM with the table due to an ambiguous name in the WO table, as for your question on the second part, I need to get Part.IXLITM WHERE Like 'RC%' AND Part.IXKITL=[The TF from above] (Sorry I actually left the last column out entirely in my post). THANKS for your help

Comment: Still not clear what you want to do. Can you post an example or some sample data?

Comment: Sure, sorry I'm not being clear enough, here are the two columns relevant to the second part are Part.IXKITL and Part.IXLITM IXLITM was used previously to pull the components including our TE# The TE itself is another Part that we manufacture so it also has individual components listed in IXLITM which I need to pull the components including our TE# The TE itself is another Part that we manufacture so it also has individual components listed in IXLITM which I need to pull Sample Data:           IXKITL   IXLITM
TE2-06718                RCWHF8                   
TE2-06718                RP-BG03

Comment: IXKITL is basically our Manufactured Product # (either a TF#(same as the WALITM number we were pulling from the WO previously) or a TE# in this case) and the IXLITM are the components going into the finished product, to complicate things all TF's are made from TE's so there are actually two-levels of components that we need to pull to verify stock for scheduling, those to make a TE and those to make a TF. THANKS AGAIN....Sorry ran out of characters

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sched.dbo.TBS.WADOCO AS WO,
Sched.dbo.TBS.WALITM AS TF,
TE.IXLITM AS TE,
CF.IXLITM AS CAP,
LBL.IXLITM AS LABEL
FROM Sched.dbo.TBS
LEFT JOIN WB.dbo.Part TE ON TBS.WAAITM = Part.IXKITA AND LEFT(Part.IXLITM,2) = 'TE'
LEFT JOIN WB.dbo.Part CF ON TBS.WAAITM = Part.IXKITA AND LEFT(Part.IXLITM,2) = 'CF'
LEFT JOIN WB.dbo.Part LBL ON TBS.WAAITM = Part.IXKITA AND LEFT(Part.IXLITM,3) = 'LBL'
WHERE WO=800059
```

Comment: Why do repeated self-joins? This can lead to a big performance issue!!

Comment: What self joins?  TBS is joining to three subsets of Part.  If IXLITM is indexed, this should perform better than cases and aggregates.

Comment: Since you're using a function (`LEFT`) on Part.IXLITM, the index will not be used